# Unable to play video files smoothly

Tags: drivers, graphics, video, video-player

All my video files keep getting stuck after being played for about 5-10 minutes. Audio keeps on playing but video gets stopped at one screen instant, and moves erratically, as if trying to keep up with audio. It doesn't matter what video player I use, or the size and resolution of the videos. I have started using Ubuntu yesterday itself, so I am not able to figure out the cause. This problem happens with online videos also. Also, this problem occurred very rarely with my old Windows 8.1 OS.

Technical Specifications of my laptop: HP Pavilion g6 32-bit laptop

Graphics Card: Intel® Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2

```
  *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:27 memory:90000000-903fffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I have got 2 proprietary drivers in use:

1. Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source
2. Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode